# Snippets where content is conditional on language in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, code-snippets

Is there a way to create a single snippet file where the content output is dependent on the language? For example, keyboard shortcut x outputs "abc" when used in a css file, but "def" when used in a javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) don't contain much processing capability — you can perform [substitutions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions) in them via [Boost-style regexes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) and [format strings](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html), and they have access to a number of [environment variables](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html#environment-variables) within Sublime such as the current file's name, the line number, etc., but beyond that they don't have much programmatic processing capability. It might be possible to set up a series of regexes that try to case-insensitively match `$TM_FILENAME` against `\.css$` and output `abc`, then immediately match `$TM_FILENAME` against `\.js$` and output `def` - only one of them will be successful.

However, in my mind such processing is much more easily handled by a [plugin](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) written in Python. The [API documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) is mostly complete (all the functions you'll need are documented there) and there are a ton of examples around the net to learn/borrow from. Here's a quick example:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class PrintScopeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        pos = self.view.sel()[0].begin()
        scope = self.view.scope_name(pos)
        if 'source.js' in scope:
            self.view.insert(edit, pos, "This is JavaScript!")
        elif 'source.css' in scope:
            self.view.insert(edit, pos, "This is CSS!")
```

Save the file in your `Packages/User` directory (accessible via **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**) as `print_scope.py`. Next, assign it to a key binding by opening your user keymap (**`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`**) and adding the following:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+p"], "command": "print_scope" }
]
```

if the file is empty. If you already have other custom key bindings, just add a comma `,` after the last one, then paste the line above after it, before the closing square bracket `]`.

You should now be able to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (or whatever other key binding you choose), and if the file's syntax is set to JavaScript it will insert the `This is JavaScript!` message at the current cursor position. If the syntax is set to CSS, `This is CSS!` will print, and if the syntax is anything else, then nothing will print.